# Как сделать возможность добавления ссылок в посте вместе с обычным текстом?

Tags: python, django

Короче говоря, есть блог с CRUD, нужно чтобы в поле ввода помимо обычного текста еще и ссылки можно было добавлять, то есть, я их добавляю, но они не работают. Мне говорят что для этого есть тег a, video (для видеоссылки) или еще что то, но это все только для того чтобы только ссылку вставить или я просто не умею их правильно использовать

Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**base.html**

`

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <header>
        <div class="nav-left">
          <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Django blog</a></h1>
            <h2><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/">Admin</a></h2>

        </div>
        <div class="nav-right">
           <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">+ New Blog Post</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hi {{ user.username }}!</p>
      {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a><br>
          <p><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/accounts/signup/">Sign up</a></p>
      {% endif %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Я новичок, буду рад любому вашему ответу, спасибо!

Comment: Покажите исходный код страницы. Как вы прописываете ссылку?  Думаю подойдет вариант `<a href="ссылка">Название</a>` Возможно потребуется добавить `autoescape off` в шаблоне. но не забываем что код должен быть из доверенного источника.

Comment: не уверен, в base.html нужно ли, но скинул его, у меня есть еще home.html и весь crud набор html файлов, если понадобится, скажите пж какой показать, я покажу

Comment: тот файл который выводит эту ссылку остальные в принципе не важны. и попробуйте вставить ссылку в формате как писал выше.. что получится?

Comment: естественно получается просто выделенное слово, на которое если нажать, то тебя перекинет по ссылке, которую ты указал в href, я имею ввиду, что ты пишешь в поле какой то текст и вставляешь туда ссылку, чтобы эта ссылка работала, а не просто ссылку или слово про которое я говорил выше <a>Word</a>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531763/user-entered-links-display-as-text-in-django Вот ответ -------------------